# Does BAFO "BF-810 USB to Serial Adapter (DB9)" supports full serial port?

Tags: usb, serial, rs232, interface

Does [**BAFO BF-810 USB to Serial Adapter (DB9)**](http://bafo.com/products/adapter/usb-cable-adapter/bf-810-usb-to-serial-adapter-db9.html) support full serial port (**hardware flow control**) functionality?

If not, how can I test full serial port functionality using serial port only with TX, RX?

Comment: Get yourself some LEDs and jumper wires, use appropriate host serial APIs to write and read the lines, and find out.

Answer (score 1):

When RS-232 cables were everywhere, a standard piece of test equipment was a small block with D connectors on the ends and LEDs on one face labeled for each significant signal. A quick check shows that such devices are still made, [here's a typical example](http://amzn.com/B004OT995U) available for about US$11.

I also have a variety of null-modem, gender changers, and 9 pin to 25 pin in my toolbox.

A device like this gives quick confirmation that only the expected pins are driven when attached to each device, and can be left inline to verify that the data and handshake signals are in use.

This does only confirm that the output pins have signal conditioning. It ought to be safe to assume that if `TXD` is driven, then `RXD` can receive, and similarly for `RTS`/`CTS` and `DSR`/`DTR`.

Answer (score 0):

Likely it has hardware flow control and you can choose to use that function or not.

Since mainstream chip support hardware flow control function, likely, the chip inside this unit has it. Even if the chip has it, depending on manufacturer, it may not be connected to the 9 pin connector, for cost reasons.

However, as modern systems is fast, most can work without hardware flow control.

Try connect rx and tx and see. In rare case of dropping data, select lower speed.

Or you can choose to add hardware flow control wiring and enable the function in software.

Comment: The real question is not if the USB-serial chip inside supports it, but if the vendor provided enough level translation channels on the board to make the signals available on the connector.

Comment: It might. I checked manual http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CBwQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.ssiserver.com%2Finfo%2Fpskmeter%2FBF-810%2520Serial-to-USB%2520manual.pdf&ei=FwPhU5zvGs2MuATy04C4BA&usg=AFQjCNEIki2uQxZczHYch_E73PBfDn42kA&bvm=bv.72197243,d.c2E and it does not definitely state. Manufacturer tech support email address is on last page of manual and there is only one sure way to find out. I edit my answer to reflect.